# Android studio TCP communication and Bytebuffer

Tags: java, android, c, tcp, bytebuffer

I am currently working on a project in my school which is controlling a Robot that maps its surrounding with a lidar. The robot is already built and is sending data through Wifi (TCP/Ip Communication). 
I have to develop an Android App that can control the Robot (move forward, backward, turn...), and my Android project is composed of 3 class :
MainActivity.java, TcpClient.java and Reglages.java. 
I'm pretty sure that I managed to create the communication between the robot and the app since i can see network trafic with the network monitor of android studio, the problem is that I don't know how to save the data sent by the robot.

The Robot sends data every 90ms which is a C structure.

This is the run() method in my TcpClient class :

```
 public void run() {

    mRun = true;
    isConnected = true;
    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

        try {
            Log.i("Debug", "inside try catch");

            //receives the message which the server sends back

            inFromServer = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        //    outFromClient = new BufferedOutputStream();
            bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);




            while (mRun) {
               // Log.i("Debug", "inside while mRun");
                int b = inFromServer.read();
                if (b == -1){
                    break;
                }
                bf.put((byte) b);

                if ( bf != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(bf);


                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            Log.i("Debug","Socket closed");
            socket.close();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }
}
```

and this is where i create my TcpClient in my MainActivity :

```
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask <Void, ByteBuffer, TcpClient>{

    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(ByteBuffer message) throws IOException {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate

                publishProgress(message);
            //    Log.i("Debug","Input message: " + message);
                if(reglages == null){
                    Log.i("Debug","Création de réglages");
                    reglages = new Reglages();
                    reglages.createFromBytes(message);

                }

                else if (reglages != null){
                       Log.i("Debug","MAJ de réglages");
                    reglages.createFromBytes(message);
                }

            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();


        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(ByteBuffer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate();

    //    Log.i("onProgressUpdate","" + values);

    }
}
```

The class "Reglages" is similar to the C structure the robot sends,

```
public class Reglages {
public byte Transport[];//16 octets
public byte Etat_Moteur_Droit[];//20
public byte Etat_Moteur_Gauche[];//20
public byte ConsigneManuelle[];//8
public byte VitesseMesure[];//8
public byte Phare_Luminosite[];//2
public byte Temperature_Exterieure[];//2
public short V_Batterie; //2
public byte Etat_Sauvegarde[];//1
public byte Mode_Commande[];//1
public byte ConsigneBoucle_Ouverte_Moteur_Droit[];//4
public byte ConsigneBoucle_Ouverte_Moteur_Gauche[];//4
public byte Status_Lidar[];//1
public byte Status_Moteur_Lidar[];//1
public byte Erreur_Code_Lidar[];//2
public byte Compas[];//4
public byte ConsigneAngulaireNulle[];//4
public byte Compensation_Ligne_Droite[];//32



public void createFromBytes(ByteBuffer buf) throws IOException{

    Transport = new byte[16];
    Etat_Moteur_Droit = new byte[20];
    Etat_Moteur_Gauche = new byte[20];
    ConsigneManuelle = new byte[8];
    VitesseMesure = new byte[8];
    Phare_Luminosite = new byte[2];
    Temperature_Exterieure = new byte[2];

    Etat_Sauvegarde = new byte[1];
    Mode_Commande = new byte[1];
    ConsigneBoucle_Ouverte_Moteur_Droit = new byte[4];
    ConsigneBoucle_Ouverte_Moteur_Gauche = new byte[4];
    Status_Lidar = new byte[1];
    Status_Moteur_Lidar = new byte[1];
    Erreur_Code_Lidar = new byte[2];
    Compas = new byte[4];
    ConsigneAngulaireNulle = new byte[4];
    Compensation_Ligne_Droite = new byte[32];


    for(int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
        this.Transport[i] = buf.get();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        this.Etat_Moteur_Droit[i] = buf.get();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        this.Etat_Moteur_Gauche[i] = buf.get();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        this.ConsigneManuelle[i] = buf.get();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        this.VitesseMesure[i] = buf.get(); ...........
```

the problem is when I try to display the values of "Reglages" in logcat, it only shows 0, and I dont know where the problem is....

EDIT : I am using a for loop in the class "Reglages" to fill each attribute with the number of bytes it has in it's C structure (for exemple, the attribute "Transport" is coded on 16 bytes), is that the right way to use the bytebuffer class and the get() method ?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: Edited my post with a more precise question

Comment: You need to flip the buffer before the gets, and compact it afterwards.

Comment: @EJP I added a buf.flip() and buff.compact() before doing the get(), but it stills returns 0 in when i try to access the V_Batterie attribute... (which I'm sure should be around 12).